# calculating TH,TC,MH,MC,CH,CC

Tags: navigation

```
TC: 032°; WCA: +11°; DEV: 001° W; CH: 049°
What are TH, VAR und MH?
a) TH: 048°.
VAR: 005° E.
MH: 050°.
b) TH: 043°.
VAR: 005° W.
MH: 048°.
c) TH: 043°.
VAR: 005° E.
MH: 048°.
d) TH: 048°.
VAR: 005° W.
MH: 043°.
```

regard this question, I have a big confusion answering this kind of questions .. i would be happy for a good explanation regarding it .
I know that :

```
TH = TC + WCA
VAR = TH - MH
DEV = MH - CH
```

in regard of the question , `TH is : 32 + 11 WCA = 43.`
to find the MH i can use the deviation equation .

DEV 1 = x(MH) - 049(CH) = **x = 50**

now to get the VAR 43 - 50 = -**7 VAR**

this is were i got stuck which of course doesn't make sense ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TC ± WCA = TH ± VAR = MH ± DEV = CH
```

Let's take this one step at a time.

```
TC: 032°; WCA: +11°; DEV: 001° W; CH: 049°
What are TH, VAR und MH?
```

---

```
TC ± WCA = TH     032° + 11° = 043°.
```

---

```
CH ± DEV = MH     049° - +1 = 048°  (formula rearranged)
```

---

```
VAR = MH - TH     048° - 043° = 5°  (formula rearranged)
(positive values are westerly and negative values are easterly)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explanation , much appreciated